# not getting correct image width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem with displaying width of an image in console. I have a function that displays width of image as soon as the function is called and and after 1 second. With first one I get 0 and after 1 second I get the actual result. What I want is to get that width without having to wait 1 second so I can save it in some variable as the image is created. This is my code:

HTML

```
<div class="image-container" id="top-img">
    <!-- 1st row of images -->
</div>
```

CSS

```
.image-container {
    height: 200px;
    left: calc((100vw - 940px) / -2);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.image-container img {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    max-height: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

JS

```
var top_images = [7, 6, 9, 8, 5];
var childImg;
var img;
var top_slider;

$(document).ready(function(){
    top_slider = document.getElementById('top-img');

    insertImages();
});

function insertImages(){
    var i;


    for(i = 0; i < top_images.length; i++){
        childImg = document.createElement('img');
        childImg.setAttribute('src', 'Assets/slider-image-' + top_images[i] + '.jpg');
        childImg.setAttribute('alt', 'image ' + top_images[i]);

        top_slider.appendChild(childImg);
        img = top_slider.getElementsByTagName('img')[i];
        getImageWidth(img);
    }
}

function getImageWidth(img){
    console.log('init: ' + img.clientWidth); // get 0, I want to get actual result here - not having to create setTimeout() function
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(img.clientWidth); // get correct width
    }, 1000);
}
```

Anyone have a suggestion? I've tried using .width, .naturalWidth, and a few move ways... they all pretty much give the same result. So i guess my question is how to get width without calling any timer functions? What am I missing?

Comment: Looks to me like a race error. I'm not at my pc, so I can't test, but I think that the insertImages function is not finished before the getImageWidth is called, but after 1 second it is.

Comment: Where in code would it then be safe to get the correct width value, without using timers?

Comment: Still not at my pc, sorry! But I would say   within the insertImages function itself. Maybe I can find time later today to test.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like @asimovwasright is right. The values are not set for a few milliseconds. If you run this snippet a few times you will see that certain image widths get set at different times. You could explicitly set the width inside the loop with childImg.setAttribute('width', 51) to see the right value on the "init" console.log, but I suppose that doesn't really solve the issue of not using a setTimOut if you have dynamic widths..

```js
var top_images = [7, 6, 9, 8, 5];
var childImg;
var img;
var top_slider;

$(document).ready(function(){
    top_slider = document.getElementById('top-img');

    insertImages();
});

function insertImages(){
    var i;


    for(i = 0; i < top_images.length; i++){
        childImg = document.createElement('img');
        childImg.setAttribute('src', 'Assets/slider-image-' + top_images[i] + '.jpg');
        childImg.setAttribute('alt', 'image ' + top_images[i]);
        //get the width of the parent, then set that width into each new item
        var parentWidth = top_slider.clientWidth;
        childImg.setAttribute('width', parentWidth);
        top_slider.appendChild(childImg);
        img = top_slider.getElementsByTagName('img')[i];
        getImageWidth(img);
    }
}

function getImageWidth(img){
    console.log('init: ' + img.clientWidth); 
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("1ms: "+img.clientWidth); 
    }, 1);
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("10ms: "+img.clientWidth); 
    }, 10);
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("100ms: "+img.clientWidth); 
    }, 100);
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("500ms: "+img.clientWidth); 
    }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image-container" id="top-img">
    <!-- 1st row of images -->
</div>
```

Comment: The thing is that I want my images to have same hight as their parent element and then width so that aspect ratio is preserved. And here I want to save image width in a variable.

Comment: @PetraBenelli `max-height:100%` + image on load for getting width should do the trick

Comment: @PetraBenelli, I added two lines in the for loop to get the width of a parent  and set it into the created items.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way of getting the width into a variable by leveraging the .on(load) handler of jQuery. (at the moment, this will overwrite the var each time, so maybe consider placing it in a more accessible object.

This way you can also avoid calling another function.

Here's [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/asimovwasright/tLutxu3z/) if you want to play with it.

```js
var top_images = [350, 450, 550];
var childImg;
var img;
var top_slider;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $top_slider = $('#top-img');
    insertImages();
});

function insertImages(){
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i < top_images.length; i++){
        $childImg = $('<img class="image" />');
        $childImg.attr('src', 'https://via.placeholder.com/'+top_images[i]+'x250').on('load', function() {
          var imgWidth = this.width;
          console.log(imgWidth);
      });
        $childImg.attr('alt', 'image ' + top_images[i]);

        $top_slider.append($childImg);
        $img = $top_slider.children('img').eq(i);
    }
}
```

```css
.image-container {
    height: 200px;
    left: calc((100vw - 940px) / -2);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.image-container img {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    max-height: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image-container" id="top-img">
    <!-- 1st row of images -->
</div>
```